# How to clear a StageWebView's cookies?

Tags: flash, cookies, actionscript, oauth, stagewebview

I'm working with StageWebView with Instagram's OAuth. When I first log in on a device the StageWebView shows Instagram's log in page so the user can enter a username and password and the log in is successful. The problem is when I try to log out, at this point I try to open the Instagram's log in page in the StageWebView again but this time the StageWebView just logs in using the username and password given earlier, it looks like it saves them in a cookie somewhere.
My question is how can I clear this cookie so that I will be able to log in as a different user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the logout page instead of the login page.  It worked for me